How to find all functions of a class in Flutter?
The Auto completion shows what I am looking for. It list all the methods and fields of a given and even included inherited properties.

However, I would like to see in a separate windows like the Flutter Outline  in order to quickly jump to each definition.

However, the Flutter Outline shows only the top level functions.
It seems like Other languages like TypeScript, Kotlin and Java supports it but I BADLY need it in Dart.

quickest way, command+click to class, it will show the source class code.
Extra tips:

if it is flutter sdk class, you can find more information on
https://docs.flutter.dev/
if it is third party library, you can find its source on
https://pub.dev/ also some libraries has its own websites with
documentation.


This will show only the top level functions, so there is no need to do that.
The goal is to show all the available functions in of a class including the inherited ones at all once. This is possible in Java, Kotlin, TypeScript
